# Searching for a value in a Panda Data Frame returns inconsistent results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to search for a match in a Panda Data Frame.  I find that the results are not consistent or I'm using the wrong type of code.  I'm using the in command which is not always consistent.  If I compare values (see example) it works.  Is there an issues with the in command?

Code example:

```
import pandas as pd
report = pd.DataFrame(columns = (['col1','col2']))
report
i = 0
while i < 100:
    a = str(i)
    addthis = pd.Series({'col1':a,'col2':'AG100'})
    report = report.append(addthis,ignore_index=True)
    i = i + 1
###this will find a match but not 100 of the time%
i = 0
while i < len(report):
    if str(i) in str(report[0:len(report)]):
        print('found match on ',i)
    else:
        print('No match found on ',i)
    i = i + 1
###this will find a match 100of the time%    
i = 0
while i < len(report):
    if str(i) == report.ix[i,0]:
        print('found match on ',i)
    else:
        print('No match found on ',i)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: you should try to use more pythonic ways to loop through the dataframe, such as `for row in report.iterrows()`, instead of keeping track of the counter

Answer (score 0):

You're running into issues because you're converting the section of the dataframe into a string. If you look at what gets printed out when you use `str(report[0:len(report)])`, you'll see that it doesn't just return the value of that dataframe, but a human readable description of it. Pandas shortens this output so that it isn't really really long when you print it in the terminal.

So, it's not a bug in the `in` statement. If you need to do this, use the second piece of code from your question.

For reference, the output of `str(report[0:len(report)])` looks like this:

```
   col1   col2
0     0  AG100
1     1  AG100
2     2  AG100
3     3  AG100
4     4  AG100
5     5  AG100
6     6  AG100
7     7  AG100
8     8  AG100
9     9  AG100
10   10  AG100
11   11  AG100
12   12  AG100
13   13  AG100
14   14  AG100
15   15  AG100
16   16  AG100
17   17  AG100
18   18  AG100
19   19  AG100
20   20  AG100
21   21  AG100
22   22  AG100
23   23  AG100
24   24  AG100
25   25  AG100
26   26  AG100
27   27  AG100
28   28  AG100
29   29  AG100
..  ...    ...
70   70  AG100
71   71  AG100
72   72  AG100
73   73  AG100
74   74  AG100
75   75  AG100
76   76  AG100
77   77  AG100
78   78  AG100
79   79  AG100
80   80  AG100
81   81  AG100
82   82  AG100
83   83  AG100
84   84  AG100
85   85  AG100
86   86  AG100
87   87  AG100
88   88  AG100
89   89  AG100
90   90  AG100
91   91  AG100
92   92  AG100
93   93  AG100
94   94  AG100
95   95  AG100
96   96  AG100
97   97  AG100
98   98  AG100
99   99  AG100

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```